# iOS: migration form plist to SQLite data store

Tags: iphone, sqlite, plist

I'm using the plist for storing data in iphone application, but now there is a need to upgrade to more powerful data warehouse. Can I upgrade the application to implement migration from plist to sqllite without losing data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably.

When your app launches, if it doesn't have a database file (because it's the first time being run with updated app), read in the plist data, and write it out to your new database file.
You will have to handle translating between the format of the plist and the structure of your database.